# Post requests are not working properly with JMeter

Tags: java, jsf, jmeter, performance-testing

i have a page that contains list of posts, each post has a comment link, which onclick of it it shows a text area (with javascript) and user fills this textarea and then presses enter to post the comment (with ajax), and here is the form data i see in the browser after posting the comment:

```
feedForm:feedForm
feedForm:j_idt221:0:j_idt222:j_idt286:commentText:hi
feedForm:j_idt221:1:j_idt222:j_idt286:commentText:
javax.faces.ViewState:-1278084094245361929:-1028657209799449340
javax.faces.source:feedForm:j_idt221:0:j_idt222:j_idt286:commentText
javax.faces.partial.event:keypress
javax.faces.partial.execute:feedForm:j_idt221:0:j_idt222:j_idt286:commentText feedForm:j_idt221:0:j_idt222:j_idt286:commentText
javax.faces.partial.render:feedForm:j_idt221:0:j_idt222:j_idt286:commentText feedForm:j_idt221:0:j_idt222:j_idt286:feedcomments
javax.faces.behavior.event:keypress
javax.faces.partial.ajax:true
```

what i did is i created a post HTTP request in Jmeter and added the above form data as parameters, and when running the test plan, i get no errors,but the comment is not added.

here's my JSF code for posting the comment:

```
<h:inputTextarea id="commentText" placeholder="#{msg['writeacomment.text']}" title="#{msg['writeacomment.text']}"
                    onkeypress="if(event.keyCode == 13 &amp;&amp; !event.shiftKey){event.preventDefault();return true;}else{return false;}"
                    value="#{feedBean.commentText}" maxlength="2000" onkeyup="countChar(this, '#{msg['remaining.text']}')">
                    <f:ajax event="keypress" listener="#{feedBean.postComment(cc.attrs.value)}" render="commentText feedcomments" />
                </h:inputTextarea>
```

please advise how to fix that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that i was passing `javax.faces.ViewState` hardcoded in my post request, which was wrong, so i had to create `User defined variable` and `CSS/JQuery Extractor` for the view state in the previous request to be able to extract the view state and use it in the next request (off course in the same page).

references:

http://anahorny.blogspot.in/2011/03/jmeter-handling-dynamic-viewstate.html

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS/JQuery_Extractor